# Passing a Rcpp matrix to a function taking a Rcpp vector as argument

Tags: c++, r, valgrind, rcpp

I did a package using **Rcpp** and everything works fine. However I submitted it to CRAN and Valgrind detects some problems:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

I only have a Windows machine without admin rights, so I can't install Valgrind, and when I check  on R-hub with Valgrind there is no problem.

I'm wondering whether I'm doing something bad here. I have this function which takes a **Rcpp** vector and returns a **Rcpp** vector containing unique values of the input vector:

```cpp
Rcpp::IntegerVector unique(Rcpp::IntegerVector v) {
  size_t s = v.size();
  if(s == 0 || s == 1) {
    return v;
  }
  for(size_t i = 0; i < s - 1; i++) {
    size_t j = i + 1;
    while(j < s) {
      if(v(i) == v(j)) {
        v.erase(v.begin() + j);
        s--;
      } else {
        j++;
      }
    }
  }
  return v;
}
```

But I apply this function to a **Rcpp** matrix. I'm suspecting the possible cause of the problem is that I don't "delete" the `dim` attribute (i.e. set it to `NULL`), and since this function deletes some elements of the vector, the `dim` attribute is not correct. I mean:

```
> v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
> dim(v) <- c(3, 5)
Erreur dans dim(v) <- c(3, 5) : 
  dims [produit 15] ne correspond pas à la longueur de l'objet [4]
```

Am I right? Again, I have no way to check...

Comment: Are you trying to write a unique function? Why not use `std::unique` from stl or rather just export unique and duplicated to your package?. Also why would you want to set the dimension of length 4 to length 15?

Comment: @onyambu Looks like my post is not clear... I intentionally set a wrong dimension, to show that this causes an error. I didn't know **std::unique**, I will take a look. But my main problem is to identify the cause of the Valgrind issue, because I already bothered the CRAN team with my repeated resubmissions. I'd like to be sure the Valgrind check will be clean, next time I submit.

Comment: Well its really difficult to help when one does not know what the exact cause of the issue is.

Comment: I think it's possible to run R CMD check with Valgrind using a Github action. I'm going to try.

Comment: You should be looking for something that is not initialized, not a missing `delete`.

If you build your executable with debug info (-g flag for the compiler) then normally Valgrind will indicate the file and line number or the error. In addition if you run memcheck with `--track-origins=yes` (and also `--read-ver-info=yes` if memcheck indicates that the variable is a global or on the stack) then you will also get the file and line number of the variable that s not correctly initialized.

Comment: But `v` above is of length four, whereas your `dim(v)` implies 15 elements.  Something has got to give there. Similarly, how can you know a once-valid input matrix is still a valid matrix (i.e. dims n by k) after removal?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel That should be my English :-( I **know** that 4 is different to 15 and that my code will throw an error. This was **intentional**, to illustrate what I meant. Now I have access to Valgrind :-) Via Github actions. And now I know the issue is not related with my **unique** function, it is elsewhere. Looks like an issue with the **CGAL** library.

Comment: Gotcha. I was out traveling for a few days. I prefer UBSAN or ASAN via Docker which I find easier to handle than via GitHub Action but whatever works you -- these static analyzers are very powerful and very useful. While a pain when it "hits you" it is good that CRAN runs these.  Ask on rcpp-devel if you need a nudge.

Comment: If it helps in any way I do have [this templated unique](https://github.com/dcooley/geometries/blob/master/inst/include/geometries/utils/unique/unique_sort.hpp#L10) function

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel No admin rights, no docker. But it's fine with the Github action. My current opinion is that this is an issue with CGAL, not with my code. I will try to demonstrate that to the CGAL team today. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thank you. But I managed to use **std::unique**. The cool point with my function is that it can be used to get the unique values "up to a function", by replacing **v(i)==v(j)** with **f(v(i))==f(v(j))**.

Comment: Most people have a personal computer or laptop.  You can run Docker there, or even `gcc` directly with the UBSAN or ASAN or ... instrumentation as it is actually not that difficult (though manrginally cumbersome as you need to rebuild R with it).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel My Linux installation on my personal laptop is dead. And I lost the password of the Windows installation... or my Outlook account has been hacked, I don't know. And no way to connect to a webmail with my work laptop, they are blocked by the admins (except the Tor webmails). I have to go to a cyber coffee to reset my password.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I truly feel for your pain but this all seem to be local issues pertaining to your setup only, and I was trying to help you with general tips. Given your general productivity and number of packages you develop and look after, you may want to consider investing into a fresh developer machine.